# 3-rd decimal digit has disappeared in the output

Tags: entities

I created a field, attached it to the entity: `coefficient_to_second_side`. Type in the  database is decimal(10,3). Then I added a value: 1.001. When I select this field manually from the database, the value is correct. In the edit form it is correct:

[image]

But when I output the field on the entity page:

```
field_attach_prepare_view('event', array($entity->id => $entity), 'full');
entity_prepare_view('event', array($entity->id => $entity));
$entity->content += field_attach_view('event', $entity, 'full');
```

I get this:

```
Coefficient to second side:
1.00
```

The third digit has disappeared. How to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you type of "Coefficient" is float, you can change scale in display options for your Content Type. (admin/structure/types/YOUR_CT/manage/display). By default it's 2.[image]

Comment: I found it here: `/admin/structure/event/manage/display`. Thank you, sir :)